# How to set max-width on images on bigger devices without destroying the look on Retina-screens?

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

I've been googling but lost myself in complicated explanations.
And then I thought that someone in here might be able to help. :)
I've set up a web-page which contains both a mobile-version and a computer-version.

I'm happy with how most of it looks on all media-devices I've tried.
Although I have some elements where I want to set a max-width for bigger screens.
It's only some elements containing images, not text. Basically, the images become too big on big screens!

I get how to set a max-width for "@media screen and (min-width: XXXpx)" BUT how do I also include retina-screens in this? I don't want small retina-screens to be affected by this, only big ones...

Is there a simple solution for this?

I.e.:

```
.singel_image_container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60vw;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40vw;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  margin-left: 12vw;
}
```

Clearification:

HTML:

```
<div class="singel_image_container">
      <img class="landscape_image" src="img/alven/1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="project_description">
      <h2><i>Ädno / Älven / The River</i> Blablabla</h2>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.project_description {
  float: right;
  width: 34vw;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

.singel_image_container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60vw;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}
```

What I then want is to set a max-width on "single_image_container" and enlarge the margin on the project_description when viewed on bigger screens.

Comment: please snippet your code

Comment: Oops. I meant: @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.singel_image_container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60vw;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504520/retina-display-image-resolution-using-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

There are resolution media queries, `min-resolution` and `max-resolution`. Adding the screen width is optional.

```
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi) and (min-width: 1300px) {     
   .singel_image_container {
         width: 60vw;
    }
}
```

CSS Tricks has a [good article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) on it.